# Umbraco 7.5.6 Angular 2 integration

Tags: angular

I have troubles with integration of both platforms: Angular 2 and Umbraco 7. The problem is in brief I couldn't boot the main javascript file which is responsible for Angular 2 starting. If someone of you has already made such test please assist me. The error is the standard one.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ja3ds.png)

Comment: Are you trying to load the angular 2 scripts in the umbraco backoffice? Or on the front end of the site? Could you provide some background on what you've already tried? It would also help us to see some code snippets. Give us as much info as you can.

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco currently uses Angular 1.x for its back-office implementation.  If you are trying to extend the back-office, I recommend reviewing the "Extending Umbraco" section of the documentation and specifically the ["Property Editors" section](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Extending/Property-Editors/).

If you are trying to use Angular 2 on the front-end in the Views / Partials, then that should work like you would normally include Angular 2.

Comment: The problem was in the routing.I still don't understand the navigation in Umbraco. What do I mean? When you create one page under "Home" for example, Umbraco generate the hyperlink as follows: "localhost/page-name/controller route". I don't understand how to manage this appropriately. Because I want just one simplified navigation - "localhost/contoller-route". I saw I have navigation management in the Back Office, but this is useful only when start the respective page from it. I'm talking about the "redirect url management" available above the content functionality in Umbraco.

Comment: I think your problem is related to routing and who is in charge for URL managment. You need to make Umbraco hand the routing over to Angular 2 router. 
You can find more info if you go through this tutorial in the "Routing" section.
    https://24days.in/umbraco-cms/2014/angular-powered-frontend